# Is it better ASTRA 19.2°E or 28°, in central continental europe?

Tags: telecommunication, wireless-communication

I'm trying to tune my satellite receiver, particularly to receive the signals of the Astra satellites, which are ASTRA 19.2E and ASTRA 2 at 28º East.

[image]

Looking at the picture the signal from ASTRA 28 should be focused on the UK (red circle which encloses Great britain) and ASTRA 19° on central europe (blue square). 
What I observe in Italy, is the opposite: I receive a signal of 72% power strength from ASTRA 19 and of 92% from ASTRA 28°. How is that possible?